# Trying to create website header, there's a small space in left/top that won't go away

Tags: css, html

```css
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans';
 * {
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
}
#headerpanel {
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding 0px;
  border: 0px;
}
```

```html
<title>Test Site</title>
<body>
  <div id="headerpanel">
    TEST
  </div>
</body>
```

What I'm trying to do is create a "header" that would start from the very left of the site to the very right, from the very top around 20px down.

[image: Space?]

But when I test the site, I see that there's this little space in top-left...
How do I get rid of it?

Comment: set `margin: 0` to `body`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
body,html { 
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to reset the browser default margin style for `body`.

```
body {
    margin: auto;
}
```

Have a look at your box-model through the "*Computed*" tab in your browser IDE/developer tool.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in your CSS

```
body{
  margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove body margin left side

```css
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans';

* {
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
}

#headerpanel {
    display: block;
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding 0px;
    border: 0px;
}
body{margin: 8px 0px; }
```

```html
<title>Test Site</title>
<body> 
<div id="headerpanel">
TEST
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Either I have misunderstood your question or all of the other answers have done so.  I always thought that `margin: 0;` fixed the problem and it does on some browsers but Safari and Chrome to name a few add that little border.  The code you should use `top: 0; left: 0;` to align with the edge of the page.

```css
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans';
 * {
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
}
#headerpanel {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;/* since we are moving it left a little, we use right: 0; instead of width: 100%; */
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
}
```

```html
<title>Test Site</title>
<body>
  <div id="headerpanel">
    TEST
  </div>
</body>
```